# Chaining methods/functions after initialisation in Swift

Tags: initialization, swift4, xcode9

When I look at answers on Stack Overflow, I often will see something like the following (this is just a snippet, I know the code isn't truly complete):

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let jsonData = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
return jsonData.person
```

Why would you declare `decoder = JSONDecoder()` and then use `decoder.` on the next line? Wouldn't it be simpler to just do:

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
```

Is this a stylistic thing or is there a technical reason for this?

(Sorry for asking this as a whole question. I tried to just ask it as a comment, but you have to have 50 rep to put a comment which makes it hard to ask simple questions like this, even though that is described as a valid thing to do in the comments).

Comment: These two are equivalent. I wouldn't sweat the difference. Sometimes people will split it on separate lines for clarity's sake. And sometimes we set `decoder` variable so that we can do additional configuration of it before we use it (e.g. specify date decoding strategy or whatever). So once you're used to having to configure your decoder occasionally, you get used to having a dedicated local var to hold it. But in your example, it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @Rob That makes more sense, thank you.